# Facing issues when using @JsonCreator with nested Json objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some old code which is working fine but now i want to use @JsonCreator in domain objects and i am able to re-factor all stuff but i am now stucked in one issue. In one scenario i have Json Structure like:

```
  [{
    "name" : "John",
    "emailAddress" :"stucked@gmail.com" 
  }]
```

But in java backend i have structure like:

```
class Employee {
    public final String name;
    public final EmailAddress emailAddress;

    Employee(final String name, final EmailAddress emailAddress) {
        this.name = name;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    Employee() {
        this(null, null)
    }
 }

class EmailAddress {
   public final String address;

   EmailAddress(final String address) {
       this.address = address;
   }

   EmailAddress() {
      this(null);
   }
}
```

So I am trying like :

```
class Employee {
    public final String name;
    public final EmailAddress emailAddress;

    @JsonCreator
    Employee(@JsonProperty("name")final String name, 
             @JsonProperty("emailAddress")final EmailAddress emailAddress) {
        this.name = name;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}    

class EmailAddress {
   public final String address;

   @JsonCreator
   EmailAddress(@JsonProperty("address")final String address) {
       this.address = address;
   }
}
```

Now the problem is in using @JsonProperty with "emailAddress" field in Employee domain object and then @JsonProperty inside EmailAddress Object with "address" because in Json i dont have any "address" property and due to which JsonParsing error is coming.

Well problem can be easily solved if i declare emailAddress as String instead of EmailAddress and remove EmailAddress object but address field of EmailAddress object is used at many other places, modification of which require lot of effort and there are lots of such cases. Is there any other solution??

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is your problem here? If the goal is to allow both of these:

```
"stucked@gmail.com" 
{ "address" : "stucked@gmail.com" }
```

it should already work: Jackson figures out that single-String constructor may be used if JSON String is found; and setters/fields if a JSON Object is found. You just need to ensure names match ("address" vs "emailAddress").

Comment: I have just added more explaination to the question. Actually the problem is "address" field inside EmailAddress object because i dont have any address property in Json and i want to map value of emailAddress to both "emailAddress" of Employee  and "address" of EmailAddress because i don't want to modify domain objects or remove EmailAddress.

Comment: Ok. Just remove that `@JsonProperty` from within creator -- it will then bind the String as I explained. Then JSON String is used to construct `Employee`, which is then assigned with property. Adding `@JsonProperty` in there confuses things because a JSON Object would now be expected, instead of a String.